# How to recognize that one js file loaded?

Tags: javascript, onload

I try to display progress bar when page loading.  I want change width of progress bar after js files loaded .At the final after load all documents set with of progress bar to 100% .Now I need to **recognize js files loading with javascript**.
Is this possible ? Please advice.

Comment: explain yourself with code

Comment: Do you simply want to detect the file being loaded, or do you want to detect the functions that are queued in those files being finished?  If the former, Mikhail has a crude example of something you could build upon.

Answer (score 3):

For internal js files loading recognition:

As functions and variables can be accessed from another file you can set the value of global progress variable and display it's value by calling the function

```
//on page or head js file
var progress = 0;

function displayProgress()
{
//show progress based on 'progress' variable
}
//file1.js
progress += 10;
displayProgress();
...
//file2.js
progress += 20;
displayProgress();
...
```

For external js files there is good [article](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/how-to-detect-when-an-external-library-has-loaded). The main idea is to periodically check existense of external functions (`typeof fixpng =='function'`) and if it exist - stop checking and display progress.

> Here's the JavaScript code to load the external library with a
>   callback passed in:
>
> ```
>  function loadExtScript(src, callback) {   var s =   document.createElement('script');   s.src = src; document.body.appendChild(s); // if loaded...call the callback }
> ```
>
> Firefox allows you to listen for the onload event on the script
>   element:
>
> `s.onload = callback;`
>
> With Internet Explorer you can wait for a state change on the script
>   element:
>
> `s.onreadystatechange = function() {   if ( this.readyState != "loaded"
>   ) return;   callback.call(); }`
>
> The problem comes with Safari - there's no event change for Safari, so
>   we can't tell when the script has loaded. This is the solution I came
>   up with (and this solution should also work with Opera):
>
> ```
> function loadExtScript(src, test, callback) {   var s = 
>
> document.createElement('script');   s.src = src;  
> document.body.appendChild(s);
>
>
>   var callbackTimer = setInterval(function() {
>     var call = false;
>     try {
>       call = test.call();
>     } catch (e) {}
>
>     if (call) {
>       clearInterval(callbackTimer);
>       callback.call();
>     }   }, 100); }
> ```
>
> The function takes a test as a parameter. Since you are the designer
>   of the app, you'll know what successful test is. Once this test is
>   true, it will execute the callback. A simple test could be to check
>   whether a function exists, for example:
>
> ```
> loadExtScript('/fixpng.js', function() {   return (typeof fixpng ==
> 'function'); }, myCallbackFunction);
> ```

Comment: The trouble with this is that the script files will probably be external resources, because if they weren't, they ought to be more or less combined into one file. Of course we don't know enough about the environment to say for sure...

Comment: Updated my answer for internal and external js files

Answer (score 1):

If you know **at least one defined namespace** (almost all libraries and plugins have it: e.g. jQuery, jQuery.ui, jQuery.mobile, toastr, DataTable, etc.) **or one global variable name** introduced by the script files which are being loaded, then you can do this:

```
(function(undefined) {
    var scriptFilesLoaded = false,
        files = [],
        timer = setInterval(function(){
            try {
                files = [
                    jQuery, 
                    jQuery.mobile, 
                    jQuery.ui,
                    someGlobalVariableName
                ];
                if(files.indexOf(undefined)<0){
                    scriptFilesLoaded = true;
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }
            catch(e) {
                console.warn('Preloader in action: Script files not loaded yet.');
            }
        },200);
})();
```

It doesn't matter if the script file is remote or local.